# com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: execute timed-out and no fallback available

Tags: java, maven, groovy, integration-testing, wiremock

I am writing an test class for Integration Testing using groovy file

My Groovy File :

```
@UseModules(value = [MiddleModule])
class MiddleServiceIT extends Specification{


@Inject
MiddleService middleService

@Rule
public WireMockRule Server = new WireMockRule(wireMockConfig().port(9090));


def 'validate config'() {
    expect:
    middleService != null
}

def 'validate get'() {

   /* String urlPath = 'http://localhost:8889/middle/?acctID=80873000101&vodSource=ais&headendID=louis&activeOnly=true&limit=50&startDate=2014-10-09&inclNonSyncData=test' */

   String urlPath = 'http://localhost:8889/middle/'
    given:
            Server.stubFor(get(urlPathEqualTo(urlPath)).willReturn(MiddleServiceStub.buildSuccess()))
    when:
    MiddleMessage response = middleService.get( '80873000101','ais', 'louis', 'true', '50', '2014-10-09', 'test')

    then:
    response != null
}
```

}

Here my requirement is when it hits that URL, it has to give the response which I mentioned in the stubFor call.

My Original Method :

```
@Override
public MiddleMessage get(String acctID, String vodSource, String headendID, String activeOnly, String limit, String startDate, String inclNonSyncData){
   String url = rentalsMiddleBaseUrl +  "/?acctID=" + acctID +  "&vodSource=" + vodSource +  "&headendID=" + headendID +  "&activeOnly=" + activeOnly +  "&limit=" + limit +  "&startDate=" + startDate +  "&inclNonSyncData=" + inclNonSyncData;
   System.out.println("***** For Test URL "+url);
   return (MiddleMessage) commandBuilder.build(url,MiddleMessage.class).execute();
}
```

My Stub Method in MiddleServiceStub Class:

```
public static ResponseDefinitionBuilder buildSuccess() throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
     MiddleSet middleSet = new MiddleSet();
    MiddleMessage middleMessage = new MiddleMessage();
    middleMessage.setMiddleSet(middleSet);
    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(middleMessage);
    ResponseDefinitionBuilder responseDefinitionBuilder = ResponseDefinitionBuilder.like(ResponseDefinition.created()).withBody(json);

    return responseDefinitionBuilder;
}
```

When I run the above code using maven command "clean install" it is giving the following exception

```
validate get(com.config.MiddleServiceTest)  Time elapsed: 1.918 sec  <<< ERROR!

com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: execute timed-out and no fallback available.
at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.getFallbackOrThrowException(HystrixCommand.java:1646)
at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.access$1900(HystrixCommand.java:103)
at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$TimeoutObservable$1$1.run(HystrixCommand.java:1023)
at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextRunnable$1.call(HystrixContextRunnable.java:41)
at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextRunnable$1.call(HystrixContextRunnable.java:37)
at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextRunnable.run(HystrixContextRunnable.java:57)
at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$TimeoutObservable$1$2.tick(HystrixCommand.java:1047)
at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$1.performBlockingGetWithTimeout(HystrixCommand.java:627)
at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$1.get(HystrixCommand.java:522)
at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.execute(HystrixCommand.java:431)
at com.client.MiddleService.get(MiddleService.java:72)
at com.config.MiddleServiceTest.validate get(MiddleServiceTest.groovy:22)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
```

Answer (score 1):

The parameter you pass to `urlPathEqualTo(...)` should be a relative URL, not absolute.

I don't know if this is what's causing the exception you've pasted, but WireMock will return a 404 given your current setup, which I suspect isn't what you want.

Comment: even though I use relative URL, its not working again getting that same exception..
In original method, the following step should not get executed commandBuilder.build(url,MiddleMessage.class).execute();  here It should mock my response

Comment: Did you set ``rentalsMiddleBaseUrl`` to be WireMock's base URL?

Comment: That was the mistake, In rentalsMiddleBaseUrl I took different port number, after changing it to 9090, its working fine